# Laravel 5.1 login register display custom error messages

Tags: php, error-handling, laravel-5.1

I was start working with basic Auth in Laravel, described here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#included-authenticating

Everything works properly, but I need to know, where can I find these strings and where I can edit them.

I need to display custom error messages like "**Bad credentials**", "**Please fill all inputs**" for register ... "**Email already registred**" etc.

But I do not know, how can I do that.

Which method, or which file to edit to do that.

My login form looks simple from docs:

```
<form method="POST" action="login">
{!! csrf_field() !!}
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
<div>
    Email
    <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
</div>

<div>
    Password
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
</div>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
</div>

<div>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</div>
```

Register form too:

```
<form method="POST" action="register">
{!! csrf_field() !!}
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
<div>
    Email
    <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
</div>

<div>
    Password
    <input type="password" name="password">
</div>

<div>
    Confirm Password
    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation">
</div>

<div>
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</div>
```

Thank you very much, have a great time!

Comment: Try to check documentation laravel about Validation